# Hmm... we didn't recognise that application error message

Tags: xero-api

I've been implementing the API sample from GitHub. In my development environment I can logon using the OAuth method, and obtain a token and perform the query request on the XERO. If I deploy, I can't get the application to work because of the errormessage 'Hmm... we didn't recognise that application.' I can logon, then select the instance to work upon and then the error message appears. For some reason i can't obtain a token:
I get a https://app.xero.com/oauth/APIAuthorise?oauth_token= 
message, in my dev env. I get a token. 
I found several posts regarding this message on the Xero forum. It is written that it has to do with TLS and I should upgrade to 1.2 My issue is that my connection is already tls1.2, I verified. I tried two different hosts to do an extra check but with the same result (virtual windows 2008 server and Linux)
The Question is how to solve this issue. Again my application is working well on development, but not when I deploy. The development system is running under W10 / Xampp and PHP 7.2. My production environments are a regular Linux host (not sure what) and a virtual Windows 2008 server with uniform server. 
The code is very similar to the original sample as published on GitHub, so I didn't post it here.

Comment: Have you set the correct callback URL through https://developer.xero.com/myapps/? You may need to create a new one for the production environment.

Comment: I have it working well on my development system, but not on my prod. environment. Can you point me to the differences what the connection string should be? I tried numerous things but no luck at all.

Comment: When you register your app at Xero, you have to set a callback URL. This dev environment callback URL will be different in your prod environment. What's the callback URL and what's the URL of your prod and dev site?

Comment: My test account is already dead, will create a new one.